# Unable to extract 608/708 captions with latest ccextractor version

Tags: video-processing, closed-captions

I have successfully extracted 608 captions and generated a webvtt file on my Mac with the brew install ccextractor v0.88

This is the command

`ccextractor file.mp4 -out=webvtt`

And I get a populated webvtt file with style, timestamps and closed captions

Here are the compilation instructions for ccextractor
https://github.com/CCExtractor/ccextractor/blob/master/docs/COMPILATION.MD#macos

But when I brew install the latest version .094 I get the error below

```
[CEA-708] dtvcc_handle_G0: Window has to be defined first
[CEA-708] dtvcc_handle_CWx_SetCurrentWindow: window [0] is not defined
Segmentation fault
```

I tried to alter the command a bit like so

`ccextractor -608 file.mp4 -svc 2 -out=webvtt`

`ccextractor -708 file.mp4 -svc 2 -out=webvtt`

But that doesn't output anything to the vtt file.

I think there is something going on with the new 708 decoder; I checked commits in ccextractor and see that the decoder was changed from C to Rust.

But that information hasn't led me to figure out how to resolve the issue.

I also have compiled the latest version of ccextractor on Linux specifically Debian and I get the same errors but interestingly when I install via apt-get it works and generates a populated vtt file with the original command above.

How can I generate the webvtt from 608 captions with the latest version of ccextractor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled a previous version of ccextractor (version 0.88) and used that as the zip for the Lambda which works perfectly for 608 to webvtt. I am reporting the issue to ccextractor github repo. For now, I will just continue using this older version

Answer (score 0):

Install cc extractor

For ubuntu,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install ccextractor
```

Clone cc extractor from github to videos folder in our system
https://github.com/CCExtractor/ccextractor

```
git clone https://github.com/CCExtractor/ccextractor 

cd ~/Videos
cd ccextractor/linux
./build
```

Right click video -properties-
parent folder path copy

```
./ccextractor pathname
./ccextractor /home/user/Videos
```

Now open the video. Then you can see the video with subtitles : )